# MySql, date datatype. Query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called Driver. There is a column called birthDate in date datatype.
it is entered as '1995-05-18' `YEAR-MONTH-DATE`

I need to do a query to list all drivers who were born in the years 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, and 2000.

This is what i thought.

```
SELECT name FROM Driver WHERE birthDate IN (1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000);
```

How do I do this? so it can look for year.

DESCRIBE Driver;

```
Driver
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name      | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birthDate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM Driver
WHERE YEAR(birthDate) IN (1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000);
```

You need to use the `YEAR()` function to compare only years. And there's no `AND` in `IN (list)` syntax.

Comment: Oh thanks. so if I want to search by date I need to say DATE(birthDate) right?

Comment: birthDate is already a `DATE`, so you don't need to do anything for that. If it were a `DATETIME` you would have to do that.

Comment: I mean, if I want to list all the people who were born on the 15th <- that is the date.

Comment: Then you would use `DAY(birthDate)`. See [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)